# JSON data structure assistance

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to construct some paging for a WebApi I'm writing.
I need to return back the total of all records along with the request display amount in JSON.

***EDIT***

Ok, so taking your adivce  onbaord, i serialize my object, but i stil get the black slashes.

```
"[
    {
        \"RowNumber\": 1,
        \"TotalRows\": 10,
        \"TotalDisplayRows\": 10
        \"Sender\": \"MNBLGB2L\"
    },
    {
        \"RowNumber\": 2,
        \"TotalRows\": 10,
        \"TotalDisplayRows\": 10
    },
    {
        \"RowNumber\": 3,
        \"TotalRows\": 10,
        \"TotalDisplayRows\": 10

    },
    {
        \"RowNumber\": 4,
        \"TotalRows\": 10,
        \"TotalDisplayRows\": 10

    },
    {
        \"RowNumber\": 5,
        \"TotalRows\": 10,
        \"TotalDisplayRows\": 10
           }
]"
```

Code that creates this is :

```
        List<Summary> results = MtFacade.GetSummary(query);

            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);

            return jsonData;
```

the Summary class is :

```
[Serializable]
    public class Summary
    {
        public int RowNumber { get; set; }
        public int TotalRows { get; set; }
        public int TotalDisplayRows { get; set; }
    }
```

So, using both Javascript serializer and JSON produces the back slashes:

[image: screen grab within VS]

***EDIT ****

GetSummary is in my Business Layer, which  is an interface from the datalayer:

```
public static List<Summary> GetSummary(string query)
        {
            return MessageRepository.GetSummary(query);
        }
```

this is the interface:

```
List<Summary> GetSummary(string query);
```

which is used in the datalayer, taking advantage of dapper:

```
  public List<Summary> GetSummary(string query)
        {
            using (var block = new TransactionBlock())
            {
                var results =
                    TransactionBlock.Connection.Query<Summary>(query, transaction: TransactionBlock.Transaction)
                        .ToList();
                block.Commit();
                return results;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't create a `StringBuilder` (I assume that's what `sb` is). Instead, create a `PageTotals` object that has the necessary fields, then serialize that.

Comment: You're serializing a string! You don't serialize strings, you **de** serialize strings to objects. You serialize objects to strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a Json file in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921652/how-to-write-a-json-file-in-c)

Comment: If your building the JSON by hand, you don't need Json.Net

Comment: No, you do not need to construct the JSON by hand. That is a **bad** idea. Instead, use a library such as [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) that can add properties to the JSON on the fly.

Comment: @mason: It's not a bad idea. It's harder but perfectly valid.

Comment: @Liam I did not say it wouldn't be valid. It said it would be a **bad** idea. The chances of it ending up valid are not good, and it'll be a pain to maintain, and there is NO reason to create JSON by hand when there are perfectly good *free* and *efficient* libraries to create it for you.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee Regarding your edit, please show the **code** you're using. Also, please clean up your question so that it's not a bunch of hard to follow edits. Make it fully encompass the question.

Comment: Okay, your updated code is working for me. I suspect that what you're copying it from is adding the backslashes, as if you were copying it out of the debugger. Try writing to the console or a log or emailing the results to yourself.

Comment: Like I said those backslashes are **not in the actual string**. You're just seeing them because that's how the debugger displays strings that contain inner double quotes. Write the string to a log file, or to the [debug console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline), or send it to yourself via email. Or test your Web API call. You'll see the backslashes aren't in there. Also, your debugger is showing that you're using the built in `JavaScriptSerializer`. I highly recommend sticking to one serializer (Json.NET being preferred.)

Comment: Provide your `GetSummary()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote peeps :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should not **create** your json by your self. You should let JSON.net do the job for you by passing the object to it.

That takes care of validation and is performant that the `StringBuilder` you are using.

Create a class with necessary properties and serialize it instead using `.JsonConvert(myObj);`

Comment: upvoted, I got your back @Amit , this is the only right answer

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a JSON and serializing it again as JSON.

That is a bad idea, at least, when you 'just' want JSON.

You have two options:

1. Keep generating the JSON yourself.
2. Create an object and serialize it as JSON using `JsonConvert`.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee: How do you get that text? Using Visual Studio or an actual file? Visual Studio shows you the escaped string.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class to store your data, then serialize that.

```
public class Summary
{
    public int RowNumber {get; set;}
    public int TotalRows {get; set;}
    public int TotalDisplayRows {get; set;}
}

Summary pt=new Summary();
pt.TotalRecords=10;
pt.TotalDisplayRecords=10;
pt.RowNumber=1;
string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pt);
```

Comment: mason, i think you're correct. So, taking this approach, can i combine two objects into one JSON string?

Comment: see edit. my response was off the back of your suggested answer.