# Json String Syntax in C#

Tags: c#, json, string

I just have a quick question. I have this JSON string in C#, and I'm wondering if it's correct.

```
 var json_data1 = "{\"serverName\": \"" + ServerStats.serverName +
               "\",\"cpuLoad\":\" " + ServerStats.cpuLoad +
               "\",\"memLoad\":\" " + ServerStats.memoryLoad +
               "\",\"drive0\":\" " + ServerStats.drive0 +
               "\",\"drive1\":\" " + ServerStats.drive1 +
               "\",\"drive2\":\" " + ServerStats.drive2 +
               "\",\"drive3\":\" " + ServerStats.drive3 +
               "\",\"drive4\":\" " + ServerStats.drive4 +
               "\",\"service0\":\" " + ServerStats.testService0 +
               "\",\"service1\":\" " + ServerStats.testService1 +
               "\",\"service2\":\" " + ServerStats.testService2 +
               "\",\"lastBoot\":\" " + ServerStats.lastBoot + "\"}";
```

**Is there anything wrong syntax wise with my JSON string?**
The reason I'm asking is that the JSON string posts to my API if I take out `",lastBoot:" + ServerStats.lastBoot`, but when that line is added into the JSON string, it does not work. Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

**EDIT: I updated my JSON string above, will this one work?**

---

Comment: Yes, you need quotes around everything.  You'd be better off using a serialiser, like [newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), to do this work for you rather than manually constructing strings.  For validating things, get the contents of `json_data1`, and stick it in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: FYI, use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is it a possibility for you to use a Json parser like Json.Net: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json ?

Comment: If you produce your Json you can validate it using [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @Thomas I will check out newtonsoft now. Thank you. I have edited the json string, as I uploaded the wrong one.

Comment: _"it does not work"_ -> in what way?

Comment: @JamesThorpe, is in it does not post to my api. And like said too, I will check newtonsoft :)

Comment: Can you post the final result, i.e. the value of `json_data1` ?

Comment: @Rui, this is what the final result: `{
    "ID": 9,
    "serverName": "ckhgjhghkjg",
    "cpuLoad": "10",
    "memLoad": 12,
    "drive0": 8,
    "drive1": 9,
    "drive2": 10,
    "drive3": 13,
    "drive4": 16,
    "service0": "testService0",
    "service1": "testService1",
    "service2": "testService2",
    "lastBoot": "20-10-2013 09:00:00",
    "Stamp": "Feb  5 2016 12:24PM"
  }`

Comment: @avantvous Seems like valid json, I checked it here: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/. It might be the case that your problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent on building this your self and [not using a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921652/how-to-write-a-json-file-in-c) then this should do it:

```
Stringbuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("{");
sb.AppendFormat("serverName:'{0}',", ServerStats.serverName);
...etc
sb.Append("}");
var json_data1 = sb.ToString();
```

your json should be in the format

```
{serverName:'myserverName', cpuLoad:'myCpuLoad',....}
```

You can validate you Json using [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/)