# System.IO.FileNotFoundException on an output file

Tags: c#, file

Not sure what could cause this on an output file.  File is created globally here:

```
    static string dt = DateTime.Today.ToString("MMddyyyy");

    static string filename = "CBI_" + dt + "_providers.json";
    static string filepath = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Outpath"]);

    System.IO.TextWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(filepath + filename);
```

and written to here:

```
 writeFile.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListALL));
```

This works fine from my local machine but throws the exception on our application server, even after creating this file in specified path and with specified name but with 0 bytes.

Comment: Is `filepath + filename` a *valid* path?  We cannot debug your code.  Please provide us with enough information to understand what is happening.  What does `filepath` contain?

Comment: use Path.Combine for creating paths

Comment: Sounds like a file security issue.  Check the permissions of the folder and the user you are writing the file as.

Comment: When dealing with file paths I reccomend to always use `Path.Combine(path, fileName)` [Path Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: `AppSettings[]` returns a string already; there's no need for `Convert.ToString()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a Json file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921652/how-to-write-a-json-file-in-c)

Comment: This could also be an issue with using a network path that cannot be mapped from the application server.  Please provide us with additional information.

Comment: Id check for modify rights, sounds like you have create but not modify,

Comment: Added the Path.Combine but it did not resolve this.  If this were a permissions issue or an issue with the network path why would it be able to create the 0 byte file?  I am thinking it might be because the Json serializer can not be instantiated?  What would need to be placed on the server for this ...anything?