# How To Store Data On Icloud in xamarin form.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, icloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt6L4.png)This Below my data I want to store on IClouds IOS, How Can I do that ,is it possible to store on iClouds ,please give me a code for that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYJKk.png)

This Below my data I want to store on IClouds IOS, How Can I do that ,is it possible to store on iClouds ,please give me a code for that

Comment: "Please give me a code" is not an on-topic question for SO.  Please read [ask] before posting for guidance on what sorts of questions are allowed.  And it's also a good idea to read the official docs before asking questions.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/introduction-to-icloud

Comment: About storing data on iCloud, you can refer to this [Using iCloud with Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/introduction-to-icloud) and [CloudKit in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/intro-to-cloudkit).

Comment: Is There any code available to store a data ,if yea then pleas provide me link

Answer (score 0):

To save the "MyFun item" data, it is recommended to serialize the data and save it to a json file or an xml file.

For JSON serialization, you can install the Nuget package `Newtonsoft.Json`. For more info, you can refer to this [document](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

Or XML serialization, you can create an instance of [XmlSerializer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-5.0) to serializes and deserializes objects into and from XML document.

Here are some related SO threads you can refer to.

[How to write a JSON file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921652/how-to-write-a-json-file-in-c/16921677)

[Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml)

If you have got the serialized data, as mentioned in the comment, you can download official demo [Xamarin.iOS - Introduction to iCloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/introductiontoicloud/), then pass it to `MonkeyDocument.DocumentString`.