# Saving/Loading JSONS

Tags: c#, json

I'm making a simple MP3 player for one of my first C# projects, and every time you play a song I want it to save to a JSON so you can see the songs that you've recently listened to. I want it to load the JSON every time you open it and put the names of mp3s you've listened to inside a list (I'm using VS). It seems simple but I'm not very experienced with C# yet and I was wondering how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this and they all have pros/cons depending on your system. I can't say which is the best fit for you but I would start by looking into some of the C#/.NET JSON libraries because they will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you,

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

And here is a similar question with some answers you might find helpful,

[How to write a JSON file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921652/how-to-write-a-json-file-in-c)

You might also want to look into document-based databases. MongoDB, Firestore, etc. They are all collections of documents (often JSON or something very similar) to store your data with APIs for reading and writing. A document-based database would be a good option if you wanted your user's 'Recently played' to work across multiple devices, since these options would store your data remotely.

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to amazing world of C#. If you just learning try saving to a json file and reading from one. this post will give you an idea :

[How to write a JSON file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921652/how-to-write-a-json-file-in-c)

once you get comfortable with that you can try storing in the database as mentioned by DKidwell or something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server