# Could not generate .JSON file after performing Serialization in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, deserialization

Here from the following code, I want to generate JSON file using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` Serialization. But in my case It just runs the program on console and could not generate `.JSON` file.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GradeSheet gradeSheet = new GradeSheet();

    Console.WriteLine("Student Name: ");
    gradeSheet.StudentName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Roll Number: ");
    gradeSheet.StudentRollNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Class (present): ");
    gradeSheet.StudentClass = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nEnter marks \n");
    Console.WriteLine("Marketing: ");
    gradeSheet.MaekringSubjectMarks = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Statistics: ");
    gradeSheet.StatSubjectMarks = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("MIS: ");
    gradeSheet.MisSubjectMarks = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Strategy: ");
    gradeSheet.StarategySubjectMarks = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("BRM: ");
    gradeSheet.BRMSubjectMarks = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    string gradeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gradeSheet);

    Console.WriteLine(gradeJson);
}
```

It should generate `.JSON` File

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` isn't going to write a file it's going to display the json as text in the console window. If you want to write it to a file you should look at `System.IO`. Here's a related post that should help you: [how-to-write-a-json-file-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921652/how-to-write-a-json-file-in-c)

Comment: You don't write anything to files !! .... add the following line in the end of your program `File.AppendAllText("gradeSheet.json", gradeJson);`

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem Ibram Reda already pointed out was simply that you never called a function to write anything to a file.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GradeSheet gradeSheet = new GradeSheet();

    Console.WriteLine("Student Name: ");
    gradeSheet.StudentName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Roll Number: ");
    gradeSheet.StudentRollNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Class (present): ");
    gradeSheet.StudentClass = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nEnter marks \n");
    Console.WriteLine("Marketing: ");
    gradeSheet.MaekringSubjectMarks = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Statistics: ");
    gradeSheet.StatSubjectMarks = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("MIS: ");
    gradeSheet.MisSubjectMarks = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Strategy: ");
    gradeSheet.StarategySubjectMarks = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("BRM: ");
    gradeSheet.BRMSubjectMarks = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    string gradeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gradeSheet, Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(gradeJson);
    
    string path = "C:\\YourPath\\FileName.json"
    
    File.WriteAllText(path, gradeJson);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I assume you have a class like this

```
 class GradeSheet
 {
     public string? StudentName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public int StudentRollNo { get; set; }
     public int StudentClass { get; set;}
     public double MaekringSubjectMarks { get; set; }
     public double StatSubjectMarks { get; set; }
     public double MisSubjectMarks { get; set; }
     public double StarategySubjectMarks { get; set; }
     public double BRMSubjectMarks { get; set; }
 }
```

I Added "using Newtonsoft.Json;" and the tested the code. My output is this json

{"StudentName":"behzad","StudentRollNo":1,"StudentClass":2,"MaekringSubjectMarks":1.0,"StatSubjectMarks":1.0,"MisSubjectMarks":1.0,"StarategySubjectMarks":1.0,"BRMSubjectMarks":1.0}

Isn't it ok? what's the problem with this json?

Comment: The problem they seem to be having is not the serializing, but the generating of a json file

Comment: Yes, I could not get .json file here D:\...\StudentGMS\bin\Debug\net8.0\ at this path of project